# Ruby on Rails - Switching a production app to use RVM, or upgrading Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I have a production app on a VPS, and for whatever reason, I elected not to get it up and running using RVM. I guess I must have thought that I wouldn't need to be running multiple versions of ruby since I'd only be running one app on it.

I've recently been running into issues where code that I write on my development environment, that works fine there, doesn't work right on the production server.

Being how I really can't have that happen, I checked out my version of ruby on the server, and it turns out its running 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux] (but 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0] on my development machine).

I'm pretty sure this could be the reason why I'm running into situations where code works fine on my development machine, but bugs out when I deploy it. It looks like that version of ruby might have been the first one released for 1.9.3 and is almost two years old.

So now I either need to somehow upgrade my version of ruby on the production server, or install RVM. All the articles I can find through google about upgrading ruby seem to be based on using RVM. I know there are tutorials on installing RVM out there, but I'm a little scared of doing it with an production app that is already running.

Does anyone have any recommendations or experience with taking a production app and switching it to use RVM? Or, simply upgrading my version of ruby without using RVM (this might even be easier). I need to make sure I know what I'm going since this is being used commercially already.

Much thanks in advance to anyone that can offer some insight.

Comment: I've been advised by a friend to switch to RVM, and that its advanced to do it any other way. Just worried about server/deploy configs...

Comment: Did you try your code on 1.9.3-p0 on your development system? Before upgrading make sure that its the Ruby version thats causing the problem. Also post the problem here people might help. 

About upgrading, depending upon the Application Server you are using (Passenger etc), you might have to change the config files to let it know about the new Ruby. So anyway you are going to face downtime. Installing RVM is a piece of cake (dev or production). Why not just go for RVM. What if you want to migrate your apps to Ruby2 in the future?? RVM makes it all very easy once you get it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision mostly depends on your current setup:

1. if you installed ruby without `--prefix` in the default location `/usr/local` or installed gems in shared/common location like `shared/gems` then you should go for RVM because it makes the installing new ruby independent of your running environment and will not disturb it.
2. if you installed ruby in separate location (`--prefix`) like `/opt/rubies/1.9.3-p0` and gems are installed in the default path inside of this ruby then you can install safely another ruby in new `--prefix` like `/opt/rubies/1.9.3-p374`

In any case *(except `bundle --deployment`)* using RVM will ensure your rubies are independent and do not interfere with running production - although it might require extra steps to configure applications to use the ruby - but the same/similar extra steps are required for rubies installed in nonsandard `--prefix`.

### Notes:

- gems installed with `bundle --deployment` are shared - you should not use this option as it is **not safe** for deployment
- if you did not use the above for installing gems you can check where gems are installed with `gem list -d`